# Select values from table and update them using function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I need to set branch_code as IN parameter and then select cms_rungno, cms_finayear from table and assign cms_rungno to a variable and update its value by 1. Then, return the journ_no by below format.

Here's my code I have tried so far. I have no clear idea about this.

```
FUNCTION GEN_JOURNO
  ( branch_code IN varchar2 )

  RETURN  varchar2 IS

   journ_no  varchar2;
   rungno number;

BEGIN 
--LAST_NO + 1
    SELECT cms_finayear
    FROM corpinfo.tblcommonserial a
    where cms_brncode=branch_code and cms_code='JOUN'

    SELECT cms_rungno INTO rungno  
    FROM corpinfo.tblcommonserial a
    where cms_brncode:=branch_code and cms_code:='JOUN';

    UPDATE corpinfo.tblcommonserial a
    set  cms_rungno:=rungno+1
    where cms_brncode:=branch_code and cms_code:='JOUN'
journ_no:=cms_brncode || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(cms_finayear),3,2)|| LPAD(TO_CHAR(cms_rungno),6,'0');

    RETURN journ_no ;
--EXCEPTION
   --WHEN exception_name THEN
      -- statements ;
END;
```

Comment: Did you encounter any error message?

Comment: Yes. This can't be saved. It says internal error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Had syntax mistakes in my previous code

```
FUNCTION GEN_JOURNO
      ( branch_code IN varchar2 )

  RETURN  varchar2(5) IS

   journ_no  varchar2(5);
   rungno number;

BEGIN 
--LAST_NO + 1
    SELECT cms_finayear
    FROM corpinfo.tblcommonserial a
    where cms_brncode=branch_code and cms_code='JOUN';

    SELECT cms_rungno INTO rungno  
    FROM corpinfo.tblcommonserial a
    where cms_brncode=branch_code and cms_code='JOUN';

    UPDATE corpinfo.tblcommonserial a
    set  cms_rungno=rungno+1
    where cms_brncode=branch_code and cms_code='JOUN';
journ_no=branch_code || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(cms_finayear),3,2)|| LPAD(TO_CHAR(cms_rungno),6,'0');

    RETURN journ_no ;
--EXCEPTION
   --WHEN exception_name THEN
      -- statements ;
END;
```

Comment: Yes, you do. ;)